# Elastic search - Search with 'edgeNGram' tokenizer

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic search and I am using JAVA API. 
Below is the problem I am facing.

Below is the settings, I updated

```
"settings" : {
  "index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.str_search_tokenizer.max_gram" : "5",
  "index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.str_search_tokenizer.token_chars.1" : "digit",
  "index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.str_search_tokenizer.min_gram" : "2",
  "index.settings.analysis.analyzer.str_search_analyzer.tokenizer" : "str_search_tokenizer",
  "index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.str_search_tokenizer.token_chars.0" : "letter",
  "index.settings.analysis.tokenizer.str_search_tokenizer.type" : "edgeNGram",
  "index.number_of_shards" : "1",
  "index.number_of_replicas" : "2",
  "index.version.created" : "900299"
}
```

Index source:

```
"_source" : {"message":"This message is sample of maximization","messageId":1}
```

My code to search message:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.fuzzyLikeThisQuery("message").likeText("maximizat").analyzer("str_search_analyzer");
FilterBuilder builder = FilterBuilders.queryFilter(queryBuilder);
System.out.println(builder);
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(typeName).setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH).setFilter(builder).execute().actionGet();
System.out.println(response.getHits().getTotalHits());
```

When I provide like text as 'maximizati', 'maximizatio', 'maximization' - result is coming fine.

If I provide search text less than 10 char, result did not come.

Is there any changes I need to update in elasticsearch.yml file?
Or any wrong in my settings JSON or my search query?

Comment: Why are you using fuzzy like this together with ngrams? Could you please post your current mapping?

Comment: Fuzzy queries expand into a bunch of queries, they must run out of expansions when your query is shorter and so not find the work. Why don't you increase the edgeNGram-max_gram size (this will increase you rindex size though) and use a non expanding query.

Comment: As ramseykhalaf mentioned, fuzzy expands the query in unpredictable ways, by adding / removing characters. Please notice that edgeNgram is meant for auto suggest / auto complete features, such as a google search.